# FirebaseFirestore interfering with FirebaseAuth.signout()

Tags: android-studio

I am creating an application that has register and a login. When the user has logged in, the data such as name and the last name is stored in a firestore database which is then fetched and presented on the navigation drawer header.

```
        ffstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userId = userAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DocumentReference documentReference = ffstore.collection("users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if(documentSnapshot.getString("fName") != null) {
                    headerName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                }else{
                    headerName.setText("User");
                }

            }
        });
```

After I added in this code to my project and pressed the logout button the application crashes.

```
logoutBtn = findViewById(R.id.lessonsBtn);

        logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                userAuth.signOut();
                        Intent a = new Intent(loggedInClass.this,loginClass.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        finish();
            }
        });
```

Every time i take off the firestore fetching data code the logout button works perfectly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

```
DocumentReference documentReference = ffstore.collection("users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (userAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                    if (documentSnapshot.getString("fName") != null) {
                        headerName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                    } else {
                        headerName.setText("User");
                    }
                } else {

                }

            }
        });
```